In scripture is self-defense when a man is faced against a female assailant permitted to fight
In Hinduism based on scripture can a man fight a woman if she is trying to do bodily harm to him? If not why..?

Sri Rama fought Tataka. Hanuman fought Simhika.

Make that an answer also I mean regular not asura.

Tataka is mentioned as a yakshi, not asuri.

@estimator I mean common woman lol.

as much force as necessary to defend yourself (sometimes this means killing), leave the place, and go through legal system. any more force, it's between you and your conscience. this applies whether to man, woman, or animal attacking you.

@User29449 okay obviously I am gonna defend myself regardless lol I am just curious lmao.

@Vak not really in supremely rare cases sure, but as Medhaiti stated such would generally fall under the law of assault.
